# Diverging barplot without ggplot in R

Tags: r, barplot

In my dataset I have a biomarker that according to the literature may or may not be related to the patient's gender and it is defenitely related to the patient's age. This marker defines the stage of disease.

I wanted to reproduce a barplot for the 5 stages of the disease accordingly to age and gender. I thought of a diverging barplot: the y-axis would show the stratified age and the x-axis the relative frequency of the number of patients at each stage of the disease. On one side of the y-axis I wanted the frequency for women and on the other side for men (like what happens in the image below).

Is there any way to build a diverging barplot in R without resorting to the ggplot package? I wanted to use base R.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.   In its present form it is neither on-topic on Stack Overflow, for that site it will need a minimal working code example

Comment: [`Hmisc::histbackback()`](http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/Hmisc/html/histbackback.html) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen edited! I'm sorry for being off-topic. I hope now it is ok.